# tf.image.cropAndResize throwing "method must be bilinear or nearest, but was undefined" error

Tags: node.js, firebase, tensorflow.js

I am trying to run an image categorization model in firebase cloud functions using tensorflow.js (specifically tfjs-node) but am running into the flowing error:

```
Error: method must be bilinear or nearest, but was undefined
    at assert (/workspace/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:698:15)
    at cropAndResize_ (/workspace/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:21340:5)
    at Object.cropAndResize__op [as cropAndResize] (/workspace/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:4287:29)
    at prepImage (/workspace/handlers/models.js:58:35)
    at /workspace/handlers/models.js:68:44
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async exports.isFurnished (/workspace/handlers/models.js:10:17)
    at async exports.getanalysis (/workspace/handlers/apis.js:103:16)
```

The error is being thrown by the `tf.image.cropAndResize()` function. What is strange about this error is that `cropAndResize()` should be automatically using its default value of "bilinear" as specified in the [docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#Operations-Images).

Stranger yet, when I run it locally I don't get any errors. My local machine is running node v12.16.0.

Below is my code. please note that I am only lading signature.json from the firebase storage and fetching /standardizing an image (I am not loading and running the actual ts model).

```
const { admin, db } = require("../util/admin");
const firebase = require("firebase");
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

exports.isFurnished = async (imgUrl) => {
  const sigPath = "models/signature.json";

  const signature = await loadSignature(sigPath);
  const image = await loadImage(imgUrl, signature);

  return "It worked!";
};

//signature---------------------------
const loadSignature = (filePath) => {
  let file = admin.storage().bucket().file(filePath);
  return file
    .download()
    .then((res) => JSON.parse(res[0].toString("utf8")))
    .catch((err) => err.message);
};

//Image-------------------------------
const loadImage = (imgUrl, signature) => {
  return fetchImage(imgUrl).then((image) => prepImage(image, signature));
};
const fetchImage = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const buffer = await response.buffer();
  return buffer;
};
const prepImage = (rawImage, signature) => {
  const image = tf.node.decodeImage(rawImage, 3);

  const [height, width] = signature.inputs.Image.shape.slice(1, 3);
  const [imgHeight, imgWidth] = image.shape.slice(0, 2);
  const normalizedImage = tf.div(image, tf.scalar(255));
  const reshapedImage = normalizedImage.reshape([1, ...normalizedImage.shape]);

  let top = 0;
  let left = 0;
  let bottom = 1;
  let right = 1;
  if (imgHeight != imgWidth) {
    const size = Math.min(imgHeight, imgWidth);
    left = (imgWidth - size) / 2 / imgWidth;
    top = (imgHeight - size) / 2 / imgHeight;
    right = (imgWidth + size) / 2 / imgWidth;
    bottom = (imgHeight + size) / 2 / imgHeight;
  }

  return tf.image.cropAndResize(
    reshapedImage,
    [[top, left, bottom, right]],
    [0],
    [height, width]
  );
};
```

Have I made an error that I'm just not seeing or is this a node and/or tsjs issue?

Also, adding in the "bilinear" parameter yields this error:

```
Error: Invalid napi_status: A number was expected
```

Comment: What if you specify `bilinear` explicitly ? You are running the `tf.image.cropAndResize` on firebase, aren't you ?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried this. The error then becomes: Error: Invalid napi_status: A number was expected... in theory though the original error does not make since because it should default to Bilinear automatically

Comment: You can open an issue on github

Comment: Seeing the same error when running body-pix in the browser, looks like @tensorflow/tfjs@2.8.0 introduced some breaking change, sticking with 2.7.0 for now

Comment: @ThomasVanier this is the solution. I didn't realize I had installed 2.8.0. reverting to 2.7.0 fixed it. If you would like to submit this as an answer I'll mark it best.

Comment: What are the values of `boxes` argument, `[[top, left, bottom, right]]`? Please print them out and include them in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314346/tf-image-cropandresize-throwing-method-must-be-bilinear-or-nearest-but-was-und?noredirect=1#comment115491723_65314346), TensorFlow.js version 2.8.0 seems to have introduced some breaking changes. Workaround (at the time of writing) is to keep using version 2.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with bodypix. It was working fine until this morning. Although I haven't changed anything, since this afternoon this exact error came up. It could be Tensorflow's issue. Or,

I checked on Windows 8.1. There, it works totally fine. The problem happens on windows 10.

EDIT: I am quite sure it's from TensorFlow. Not the windows. I was using CDN to get the bodypix and after updating the cdn address the error disappeared.

previous: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/body-pix/dist/body-pix.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js

Now: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/body-pix@2.0.5/dist/body-pix.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.7.0/dist/tf.min.js